# Why is require condition with or ( || )operator always false?

Tags: solidity, remix, ganache

I have an internal function which is called from an external function. At the 2 require(msg.sender == ContractOwner ... ) the result of the compare is always false, or at least it is ignored and the 2nd part after the or (||) operator is executed. In the constructor of the contract ContractOwner (type: address) is set to msg.sender.

Even if I replace msg.sender == ContractOwner by true or 1 == 1, the 2nd part after the || is executed.

I also tried placing extra ( ) around the or construction. I thought that should always return true because msg.sender == ContractOwner is true.

```
function publicMint(uint256 _numTokens) external payable {
    require(isPublicsaleActive, "Public sale paused");
    require(_numTokens * publicPrice * 1 ether <= msg.value, "Insufficient funds");
    randomMint(_numTokens);
}

function randomMint(uint256 _numTokens) internal {
    uint256 reservedAmount = whitelistReserved[msg.sender];
    require(!(isPresaleActive || isWhitelistsaleActive) || _numTokens <= reservedAmount,                                              "Can't mint more NFTs than reserved" );

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    require(msg.sender == ContractOwner || _numTokens <= MAX_MINT_PER_TRANSACTION, string(abi.encodePacked("Max mint ", MAX_MINT_PER_TRANSACTION, " per transaction")));
    require(msg.sender == ContractOwner || _numTokens + mintedPerWallet[msg.sender] <= MAX_MINT_PER_WALLET, string(abi.encodePacked(MAX_MINT_PER_WALLET - mintedPerWallet[msg.sender], " mints left for this wallet")));
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    require(totalSupply + _numTokens <= MAX_TOKENS, "Mint amount exceeds the maximum supply");
    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _numTokens; ++i) {
        _safeMint(msg.sender, IDs[totalSupply]);
        individualTokenURI[IDs[totalSupply]][0] = initialBaseUri;
        totalSupply += 1;
    }
    mintedPerWallet[msg.sender] += _numTokens;
    if (isPresaleActive || isWhitelistsaleActive && reservedAmount >= _numTokens) {whitelistReserved[msg.sender] = reservedAmount - _numTokens;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorted out that "**string(abi.encodePacked("Max mint ", MAX_MINT_PER_TRANSACTION, " per transaction"))**" was the reason of reverting. I replaced it with just a string and the everything worked as supposed. I can't see a fault in it and also tested it in a test contract where it works fine. So halve solved, but good for now.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract test {

    address public              ContractOwner;
    uint256 public constant     MAX_MINT_PER_TRANSACTION    = 5;
    constructor() {
        ContractOwner = msg.sender;
    }

    function _test() external payable {
        operator();
    }

    function operator() internal view {
        address Test = msg.sender;
        require(msg.sender == ContractOwner || 1 + 1 >= 3, string(abi.encodePacked("Max mint ", MAX_MINT_PER_TRANSACTION, " per transaction")));
        Test = msg.sender;
    }
}
```